# Read SQL into Pandas Dataframe with values for each row

Tags: python, oracle, pandas

I need to get some values from a SQL server and input the data into an existing DataFrame.

The query is as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
ids = []
for index, row in events.iterrows():
    ids.append(sql.read_sql("select ID from TABLE \
    WHERE ENT_O_ID IN (\
    select ENT_ID from ENTITIES where ENT_NAME = '{0}' \
    ) AND ENT_D_ID IN (\
    select ENT_ID from ENTITIES where ENT_NAME = '{1}'\
    )".format(
        row['A'], 
        row['B']
    ),
    connection.connection
))
```

So I get a list of dataframes in the end. How can I efficiently add the output dataframe from the query to the events data frame?

Comment: If you have a list of dataframes, you can do `pd.concat(list_of_df)` to concatenate the frames in the list into one dataframe.

Comment: I tried to concatenate, but the resulting dataframe from the SQL query does not have an index. Even with ignore_index=True it fails to add.

Comment: Every dataframe has an index, at least a default integer one. But can you show what you did and the error message it gives?